# use scrapy custom settings in scraper.py

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, scrapy

i want to run the scrapy file using scrapy runspider scrapy.py
it doesnot have the any settings file how to use custom settings like 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
but when the start_requests is called concurrently loading the all urls requests

```
def start_requests(self):

    self.urls = self.mongo.get_latest_urls(config.collection)
    for url in self.urls:
        request = scrapy.Request(url["url"],callback=self.parse ,dont_filter = True,errback=self.error_function)
        request.meta['reviewId']=self.latestreview_id
        yield request
def parse(self,response):
    pass
```

scrapy is maintaining the concurrent requests, i want only if one url is processed then it needs to load the next url

Answer (score 0):

You can set scrapy settings per spider by setting `custom_settings` spider's attribut like that

```
class MySpider(Spider):

    custom_settings = {
       'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        ...
```

More about how to deal with scrapy settings here : https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=custom_settings

Comment: it is worked but same custom settings are not working for the website consumeraffairs.com website it requesting  2 urls at a time

Comment: How do you observe that it requests 2 urls at the same time ? Can you give the full configuration of your spider that is displayed when starting the spider ?